# how to style material top tab navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

using react navigation v5 trying to style screen tab but nothing from which said in docs worked with me I have tried with that:

```js
<TopTab.Screen
  name="Home"
  component={Home}
  options={{
    tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: "red", marginRight: 9, width: 90 },
  }}
/>
```

it's not displaying any error but changes are not making any effect on the tab, what might be the reason?

Comment: Have you tried using the options inside screenOptions in the TopTab.Navigator?

Comment: this will affect all tabs , I want to customize styles for a single tab

Comment: do you use the Home Screen in a tab bar navigation?

Comment: in this case, this link will help you https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation#customizing-the-appearance

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this -

```
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName={'Route Name'}
      tabBarOptions={{
        pressColor: 'transparent',
        pressOpacity: 1,
        labelStyle: {
          fontSize: 16,
          textTransform: 'none',
        },
        style: {
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          height: 50,
          elevation: 0,
        },
        indicatorStyle: {
          backgroundColor: 'blue',
          height: 4,
        },
        tabStyle: {width: 'auto', marginLeft: 10, alignItems: 'center'},
      }}>
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Answer (score -1):

// Add style to Navigator using screenOptions

< Tab.Navigator  screenOptions={{
tabBarLabelStyle  :  {color:'white', marginRight:1}  ,
tabBarItemStyle  :  {width:100}  ,
tabBarStyle  :  {backgroundColor:'red'}
}} >